# Using CacheItemRemovedCallback to simulate a Windows Service acts different on first run

Tags: c#, asp.net

I simulated a Windows Service with the CacheItemRemovedCallback, based on this source:

[Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

Everything is working great, except from the first run after the application recycles or restart.

Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterCacheEntry();
}

private bool RegisterCacheEntry()
{
    if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[DummyCacheItemKey]) return false;

    int interval = Properties.Settings.Default.SchedulerInterval;

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(
        DummyCacheItemKey, "StartingScheduler", null,
        Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromHours(interval),
        CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,
        new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback)
    );

    return true;
}

public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    Scheduler.HitPage(Properties.Settings.Default.Dummy);
    string dirScheduler = Properties.Settings.Default.Scheduler;
    Scheduler.Manage(dirScheduler);
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == Properties.Settings.Default.Dummy)
    {
        RegisterCacheEntry();
    }
}
```

public static class Scheduler

```
public static string _DirScheduler { get; set; }

public static void Manage(string dirScheduler)
{
    _DirScheduler = dirScheduler;
    string[] schedulesCfg = Directory.GetFiles(dirScheduler, "*.xml");

    foreach (string scheduleCfg in schedulesCfg)
    {
        //scheduleData = Class to store the schedule data
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => FireAway(scheduleData));
    }
}

private static void FireAway(Schedule schedule)
{
    string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

    if (month.Length == 1)
    {
        month = month.Insert(0, "0");
    }

    // Wait Handle to Manage Access to Log File
    EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "LogFile_Shared");

    // Lock the log file
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    WriteLog("path_to_log_file", schedule, "started");
    // Release the lock on log file
    waitHandle.Set();

    // Ok until here !
    string message = ScheduleScript.Launch(schedule);

    // Code not executed from here (only after application end or recycle)
    if (schedule.Repeat == "0")
    {
        waitHandle.WaitOne();
        UpdateScheduler(schedule);
        waitHandle.Set();
    }

    // Lock the log file
    waitHandle.WaitOne();
    WriteLog("path_to_log_file", schedule, message);
    // Release the lock on log file
    waitHandle.Set();
}

private static void UpdateScheduler(Schedule schedule)
{
    // Update a xml file containing scheduler data
}
```

public static class ScheduleScript

```
public static string Launch(Schedule schedule)
{
    string message = "finished";
    string messageScheduler = string.Empty;

    using (WebClientCustom web = new WebClientCustom(10800000)) // 3 hours timeout
    {
        try
        {
            string res = web.DownloadString(schedule.Script);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.Message;
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

In the static class Scheduler, everything is executed until `ScheduleScript.Launch(schedule)`. Then, the code is not executed (the log is not updated with Status finished and the Scheduler xml is not updated either with the `UpdateScheduler` method).

I tried everything I could without success. This situation happened only when a schedule starts after the application is recycled.

This behavior happen for example if I have a schedule expected to launch at 10am and has not yet been executed and I publish a new version of the application or manually execute an application pool recycle in the same hour (10am) of the schedule.